# Process started from Java doesn't see GPUs

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I am experiencing some strange behavior running a Process in my Java application under OS X. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
ProcessBuilder boincBuilder = null;
    if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
        boincBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Grid\\BOINC\\boinc.exe");
    } else if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
        boincBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/Library/Application Support/Grid/boinc", "--dir", "/Library/Application Support/Grid/");
    }
    try {
        Process boinc = boincBuilder.start();
        Thread boincOutput = new Thread(new BoincOutput(boinc));
        boincOutput.setDaemon(true);
        boincOutput.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run the program normally, I get the following output:

```
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] cc_config.xml not found - using defaults
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] Starting BOINC client version 7.6.7 for x86_64-apple-darwin
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] log flags: file_xfer, sched_ops, task
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] Libraries: libcurl/7.39.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1j zlib/1.2.5 c-ares/1.10.0
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] Data directory: /Library/Application Support/Grid
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] OpenCL: NVIDIA GPU 0: GeForce GT 650M (driver version 10.4.2 310.41.35f01, device version OpenCL 1.2, 1024MB, 1024MB available, 29 GFLOPS peak)
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] OpenCL: Intel GPU 0: HD Graphics 4000 (driver version 1.2(Jun 10 2015 16:35:15), device version OpenCL 1.2, 1024MB, 1024MB available, 154 GFLOPS peak)
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] OpenCL CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz (OpenCL driver vendor: Apple, driver version 1.1, device version OpenCL 1.2)
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] Host name: MacBook-Pro.local
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] Processor: 8 GenuineIntel Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz [x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9]
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] Processor features: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clfsh ds acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss htt tm pbe pni pclmulqdq dtes64 mon dscpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 tpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes pcid xsave osxsave tsctmr avx rdrand f16c
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] OS: Mac OS X 10.10.4 (Darwin 14.4.0)
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] Memory: 8.00 GB physical, 114.90 GB virtual
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] Disk: 232.62 GB total, 114.65 GB free
24-Aug-2015 19:53:32 [---] Local time is UTC -3 hours
```

However, under Java, I get this:

```
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] cc_config.xml not found - using defaults
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] Starting BOINC client version 7.6.7 for x86_64-apple-darwin
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] log flags: file_xfer, sched_ops, task
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] Libraries: libcurl/7.39.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1j zlib/1.2.5 c-ares/1.10.0
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] Data directory: /Library/Application Support/Grid
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] No usable GPUs found
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] Host name: MacBook-Pro.local
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] Processor: 8 GenuineIntel Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz [x86 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9]
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] Processor features: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clfsh ds acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss htt tm pbe pni pclmulqdq dtes64 mon dscpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 tpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes pcid xsave osxsave tsctmr avx rdrand f16c
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] OS: Mac OS X 10.10.4 (Darwin 14.4.0)
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] Memory: 8.00 GB physical, 114.89 GB virtual
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] Disk: 232.62 GB total, 114.65 GB free
24-Aug-2015 19:59:23 [---] Local time is UTC -3 hours
```

Notice how it doesn't find any GPUs when running under Java. Another strange behavior is that I see two tasks under Activity Monitor, while only one is created in Windows (which is what should happen).

Could this be a bug in Java? Or a problem with the program itself?